# jQuery DataTable - Column data.toUpperCase() is not working

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, datatables, uppercase

I tried using `columnDefs` to set jQuery DataTable columns to uppercase:

```
columnDefs: [
  {
    targets: [1, 2],
    render: function (data) {
      return data.toUpperCase();
    }
  }
]
```

This works for all of the columns that I specify as targets, except for one. The attribute type is `nvarchar(max)`. I know that I can use the following to set the entire DataTable to uppercase, but I would like to do it per column:

```
<style> td { text-transform: uppercase } </style>
```

This column does display the correct data. However, when I specify it as a target in `columnDefs`, the DataTable says that it is loading and does not display any of the data.

Comment: How about using [columns.className](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.className)? Such as: `{ "columnDefs": [ { className: "upper", "targets": [ 1,2 ] } ] }`. And your CSS: `.upper { text-transform: uppercase }`

Comment: If I copy `.upper { text-transform: uppercase }` in my Index View, it says that the name 'upper' does not exist in the current context.

Comment: Did you place this `.upper { text-transform: uppercase }` in `<style>` section? Or where did you place?

Comment: Now I did and it also sets the column header to uppercase. Is there a way to just set the data to uppercase?

Comment: My bad, should be `td.upper { text-transform: uppercase }`. For the styling to data-row (td) with class `upper` only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can apply for [columns.className](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.className) settings.

```
columnDefs: [
  {
    className: "upper"
    targets: [1, 2]
  }
]
```

And apply this styling rule so all the `<td>` elements with class `upper` will take the effect.

```
td.upper { 
  text-transform: uppercase 
}
```